# web api: Route different from name of controller, possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have mineController.cs 
now in my route,  is it possible to do 
/api/mycontroller/myaction

i.e. I try to get route not limit to controller name

Comment: See [Attribute routing](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Web Api 2 you can use [Attribute Routing](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/mine")]
public class mineController : ApiController
{
    [Route("method1")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Method1()
    {
        //Route would be api/mine/method1
    }

    [Route("method2")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Method2()
    {
        //Route would be api/mine/method2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by using Attribute Routing.

Step 1: Enable attribute routing in `WebApiConfig.Register` method (might be on by default, I don't recall offhand):

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Step 2: Not required, but it's nice to use a `RoutePrefix` attribute for the entire controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/mycontroller")
public class mineController : ApiController
{
    ..
}
```

Step 3: Use a `Route` attribute on each method that completes the route prefix:

```
[Route("myaction")]
[HttpGet] /* or other HttpVerb */
public IHttpActionResult SomeMethod()
{
   ...
}

[Route("myaction/{id}")]
[HttpGet] /* or other HttpVerb */
public IHttpActionResult SomeMethod(int id)
{
   ...
}
```

More info here: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Was missing the config setting. `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute` to decorate your controller actions and specify any route you desire. Depending on what it is you want to do, this may be a good approach for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of using a `~` to bypass the route prefix

take this from the ms documentation

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/books")]
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    // GET /api/authors/1/books
    [Route("~/api/authors/{authorId:int}/books")]
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetByAuthor(int authorId) { ... }

    // ...
}
```